# Loads() Outputting a List Instead of an Object

Tags: python, json, list, object, python-requests

I am trying to make a simple python program that outputs a random word.
I am using the `requests` library to pull data from [this](https://random-words-api.vercel.app/word) API. I am then using the `loads()` function from the `json` library to turn a string into a python object.


For some reason I am getting a **list** output instead of an **object** output, which is then causing errors.

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://random-words-api.vercel.app/word"

r = requests.get(url)

data = json.loads(r.text)

print(type(r.text))
print(type(data))
print(data)
word = data['word']
```

The output from the `type(r.text)` is `<class 'str'>`, which is correct. 
The output from the `type(data)` is `<class 'list'>`, which is incorrect! Shouldn't it return a python object? 
The output from `print(data)` is just the random word, definition, pronounciation etc.
The output for `word = data['word']` is:
`word = data['word'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` 

So why am I getting a list rather than an object from `loads()`?

Also, if my question could be clearer in some way, please tell me for future reference.

Comment: `json.loads()` returns whatever type of object is described by the JSON data.  This could be a dict, list, string, integer, float, boolean, or None.

Comment: `list` objects *are objects*. did you mean a `dict` object?

Comment: "The output from the type(data) is <class 'list'>, which is incorrect! Shouldn't it return a python object?" That doesn't make any sense. **everything in python is a python object**. Python is a purely object-oriented language, i.e. everything is an object. A `list` is an object, an `int` is an object.

Comment: As an aside, no need to use the `json` module directly here, just use `data = r.json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "word": "Astichous",
    "definition": "Not in rows  ",
    "pronunciation": "Astikshous"
  }
]
```

that api is returning a list of dictionaries, it appears json.loads is working correctly.  you can do word = data[0]['word'] for you're current example

if you wanted it to be callable like "word = data['word']" you would need the api to return this:

```
  {
    "word": "Astichous",
    "definition": "Not in rows  ",
    "pronunciation": "Astikshous"
  }
```